# October CMS | Is it possible to disable checkboxes for certain rows or hide certain rows?

Tags: php, laravel, plugins, octobercms

I am creating a plugin which allows people to add their own payment statuses and payment methods.  There are two values in my payment statuses model which I require for a reportwidget I use in the dashboard.

My question is, is it possible to hide or simply disable the checkboxes so that other users would be unable to delete these?  I know if they really wanted to they could always delete it from say phpMyAdmin but I want to make it as difficult as possible.

As an example, I have edited the photo:

[image]

I use a Seeder to create the contents upon installation:

```
use Vektar\Crm\Models\AddPaymentStatus as PaymentStatus;
use Seeder;

class CreateVektarCrmSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $paymentstatuspaid = PaymentStatus::create([
            'add_payment_status' => 'Paid'
        ]);

        $paymentstatusunpaid = PaymentStatus::create([
            'add_payment_status' => 'Unpaid'
        ]);

    }
}
```

Payment Status Table:

```
<?php namespace Vektar\Crm\Updates;

use Schema;
use October\Rain\Database\Updates\Migration;

class CreateMartinsmithMsAddPaymentStatus extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {

        if (!Schema::hasTable('vektar_crm_add_paymentstatus')) {
            Schema::create('vektar_crm_add_paymentstatus', function ($table) {
                $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('job_id')->nullable();
                $table->text('add_payment_status')->nullable();
            });
        }
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('vektar_crm_add_paymentstatus');
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code that generates the table with the checkboxes etc?

Comment: Done, hopefully that is enough for you.

Comment: Could you add the function that you use to delete the statusses?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm afraid.  To delete them, you tick the box and hit delete. I can add the contents of controller/addpaymentstatuses/_list_toolbar.htm?

Comment: In your php code you have something that actually removes the rows from the database, add that code.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. Do you want only admins to delete the data, or you want to allow the specific user to be able to delete his own records, or something else?

Comment: Ok, so I need both of the values in my screenshot above but I do want people to be able to add their own payment statuses if they wish and delete the ones that they create but the two values that are added via the Seeder, I do not want people deleting them. The screenshot where you see two rows and one of the tickboxes have been removed is essentially what I am trying to achieve.  I do apologise if I am not coming across well.

Comment: i would say best option would be add field to table `default` mark it 1 which are defaults and no one can delete them, and when showing list just use filter `default = 0` so they don't need to see defaults, and now every thing works fine. on deletion just for safety add condition if record is NOT default then only allow deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out a way to do this.

The first thing I did was in controllers/addpaymentstatus/config_filter was add the following:

```
scopes:
  filterJobStatus:
    label: Job Statuses
    modelClass: Vektar\Crm\Models\AddPaymentStatus
    type: checkbox
    default: 1
    conditions: is_hidden <> true
```

In my database, I then added the following column:

```
$table->boolean('is_hidden')->nullable()->default(0);
```

In my seeder, I added:

```
class CreateVektarCrmSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $paymentstatuspaid = PaymentStatus::create([
            'add_payment_status' => 'Paid',
            'is_hidden' => true
        ]);

        $paymentstatusunpaid = PaymentStatus::create([
            'add_payment_status' => 'Unpaid',
            'is_hidden' => true
        ]);

    }
}
```

At this stage, the values that I add via the seeder are then filtered out and are not visible in my list, however, this doesn't stop users from simply un-filtering the list  so I then add the following to the controller I want to remove the filter status menu from:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->asExtension('ListController')->index();
}
```

I then added a file in my controller called `_list_container.htm`.

We then render the parts of the list manually:

```
<?php if ($toolbar): ?>
    <?= $toolbar->render() ?>
<?php endif ?>

<div class="row row-flush">
    <div class="col-sm-12 list-with-sidebar">
        <?= $list->render() ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will then only load the toolbar and my list but if you would like to render the filters via this method then we would need to add:

```
<?php if ($filter): ?>
    <?= $filter->render() ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

I hope this helps for anyone who would like to do something similar.